# Returning an array of multiple arrays

Tags: c#, arrays, xml, function, multidimensional-array

I don't really know if this is the correct method, but I wanna return an array of arrays in order to call the element of it in another function later.

```
 static Values RetrieveXML(string XMLFile)
 {

        using var reader = XmlReader.Create(XMLFile);

        reader.ReadToFollowing("ticket");

        reader.ReadToFollowing("lignes");
        string nombre = reader.GetAttribute("nombre");
        int ligne = int.Parse(nombre);

        Values[] _Values = new Values[ligne];

        for(int i=0; i<ligne; i++){

        _Values[i] = new Values();

            reader.ReadToFollowing("article");
            _Values[i].code = reader.GetAttribute("code");

            _Values[i].qty = reader.GetAttribute("quantite");

            _Values[i].net_price = reader.GetAttribute("net");

            _Values[i].net_ht_price = reader.GetAttribute("net_ht");

            _Values[i].tva = reader.GetAttribute("taxes");

            _Values[i].num = reader.GetAttribute("numero");

            _Values[i].valeur = reader.GetAttribute("base_ht");

            _Values[i].remise = reader.GetAttribute("valeur_remise");

            reader.ReadToFollowing("libelle");
            _Values[i].libelle = reader.ReadElementContentAsString();

            Console.WriteLine("-----------Using XMLToOrderLine--------------");
            Console.WriteLine(_Values[i].code);
            Console.WriteLine(_Values[i].valeur);
        }

   return _Values[];
}

public class Values
{
    public string code;
    public string qty;
    public string remise;
    public string valeur;
    public string tva;
    public string libelle;
    public string num; 
    public string net_ht_price;
    public string net_price; 
}
```

And then after that I wanna call by example: `Values[1].code` in another function, how can I do that?

Comment: *"if this is the correct method"* - does it works? Is it compilable without errors?

Comment: Change definition to : static Values[] RetrieveXML(string XMLFile)  Then return return _Values;  (without array).

Comment: Additional things to consider are how likely is this contract to change? Do you need to think about making this more generic so it will work despite those changes?

Comment: Oh yes my bad thank you @jdweng

Comment: IMHO Values is a bad name for the class and in this instact added to the confusion of what it represented. Values (singular) whould be better. Even then it doesnt tell you what the object it. Maybe "Article". This obvious has nothing to do with your issue but would help clarity.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

change your code like this:

```
static Values[] RetrieveXML(string XMLFile)
 {

        using var reader = XmlReader.Create(XMLFile);

        reader.ReadToFollowing("ticket");

        reader.ReadToFollowing("lignes");
        string nombre = reader.GetAttribute("nombre");
        int ligne = int.Parse(nombre);

        Values[] _Values = new Values[ligne];

        for(int i=0; i<ligne; i++){

        _Values[i] = new Values();

            reader.ReadToFollowing("article");
            _Values[i].code = reader.GetAttribute("code");

            _Values[i].qty = reader.GetAttribute("quantite");

            _Values[i].net_price = reader.GetAttribute("net");

            _Values[i].net_ht_price = reader.GetAttribute("net_ht");

            _Values[i].tva = reader.GetAttribute("taxes");

            _Values[i].num = reader.GetAttribute("numero");

            _Values[i].valeur = reader.GetAttribute("base_ht");

            _Values[i].remise = reader.GetAttribute("valeur_remise");

            reader.ReadToFollowing("libelle");
            _Values[i].libelle = reader.ReadElementContentAsString();

            Console.WriteLine("-----------Using XMLToOrderLine--------------");
            Console.WriteLine(_Values[i].code);
            Console.WriteLine(_Values[i].valeur);
        }

   return _Values;
}
```

just try it.

Comment: Please explain what you have changed in the code above, so all people understand the changes.

Comment: Ok thank you BigDream it work like this, i just had to change "static Values RetrieveXML(string XMLFile)" into "static Values[] RetrieveXML(string XMLFile)" and "return _Values[];" into "return _Values;"